# How to give Dictionary to the Dictionary value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have an interesting question. Does anyone know if we could give another Dictionary to the Dictionary's Value? Example:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
  {1, 333},
  {7, 555},
  {23, 111},
  .....
}
```

Is it possible, to give dict1 as value of dict2?

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary <int, int>
{
  {0, dict1},   //possible? How to do? any other ways?
  {1, 565},
  {2, 5286},
  {3, 62836},
  ....
}
```

Actually there will be variables which equals to keys of both Dictionaries and comes same time example:

```
var str = 0;
var str2 = 7;
Return will be 555;
```

or:

```
var str = 0;
var str2 = 1;
return will be 333;
```

I would like to return like this: How to do it?

```
  if (dict2.key == 0 && dict1.key == key1 or key....n)
  {
    return dict1 value
  }

else if
{
  return dict2 value
}
else 
{
 return something else
}
```

Comment: Seems to be an xy-problem but you don't tell us the x-problem. Can you show what you want to evaluate? You have a single dict2 and you want to know if any key in dict1 is contained as value in that dictionary?

Comment: sounds like an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you trying to achieve in the first place, that you thought that having an inner dictionary would be the solution for that?

Comment: @JohnPaulJohns: Where in your code is that check? I don't see a `bool` or `if`.

Comment: Don't do this. It makes no sense. And your question isn't clear at all. What value are you looking up in `dict1` when the argument is 0?

Comment: Again I edited question, hope will understand clearly

Comment: Your if/else logic accessing the various dictionaries doesn't seem to necessitate nesting any of the dictionaries. Can you explain how your need ties together with your desire to nest dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

You technically could by changing the Dictionary type to a `Dictionary<int, object>`, but it seems an odd thing to do. Especially if this is a one-value thing. I would consider something like:

```
if (key == 0)
    otherDict.GetValueOrDefault(someOtherKey, out value);
else
    dict.GetValueOrDefault(key, out value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would create a Dictionary instance for a regular variable. With `new`.

```
var dict = new Dictionary <int, Dictionary<int, int>>
{
  {0, new Dictionary<int, int>()}, 
  {1, new Dictionary<int, int>()}, 
};
```

Note that the outer dictionary has to be of type `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,int>>` because you cannot have some values be of one type and others be of another type. If that is your goal it's best to define a custom class which has an int as well as an optional Dictionary member as well as some logic that tells which of the two is currently in use.

Using "object" is usually not recommended as you fully loose type safety with that.